# Intuit POS SDK - Missing manufacturer for inventory query

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am developing against the QuickBooks POS system. I make the following request for an inventory list (in C#).

```
var request = sessionMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest(1, 0);
request.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;
var inventoryQuery = request.AppendItemInventoryQueryRq();
var response = sessionMgr.DoRequests(request);
```

The inventory list I get back does not include the Manufacturer string for each inventory item, through this string is populated in QBPOS. The field is not in the returned XML or in the IItemInventoryRet object, although everything else appears to be.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: May you please, update your question. Share if you had any further development in the QuickBooks POS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer field was added in later version of the program so you will have to specify a version 3 request to get it.

You can call "QBPOSXMLVersionsForSession" from your request object to ensure that the end user has a compatible version of POS for your request.

This shows what fields are available to what versions: https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html